# Can firebase admin json file be public on github?

Tags: node.js, git, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I'm doing a use case for an job application. First time using nodejs + firebase. After setting up firebase I see there is an xxxx-firebase-adminsdk.json file which holds among other things, private_key_id and private_key.
This is a bit different from what I am used to from react, where I know sharing the firestore config does not bear any issues.

The case is supposed to be shared in a public repository, but I'm pretty certain it's bad practice to expose this file on a public repository, right? The option would be to send it seperate via email or something instead, for them to be able to test the app?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No never.** Anyone can access your database with the xxxx-firebase-adminsdk.json file.